# sqlalchemy join two models, which relate to other 1 model

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm working on FCM notification and I need to select all my push-tokens from user_notification_tokens table with filtering by other table datetime column, but there is no relation between these two tables, but they have relation with users table.

How can I do it with sqlalchemy?

simplified schema of sqlalchemy models relations:

[image]

I've tried to do it like this:

```py
def get_tokens()
    db: Session = next(db_service.get_session())

    x_minutes_to_event = datetime.now(pytz.utc) + timedelta(minutes=config.MINUTES_TO_PRESCRIPTION)
    tokens = [
        item[0]
        for item in db.query(models.UserNotificationsToken)\
            .join(
                models.User,
                models.User.id == models.UserNotificationsToken.user_id,
            )\
                .join(
                    models.UserPrescription,
                    models.UserPrescription.user_id == models.User.id
                )\
                    .filter(
                        models.UserPrescription.visiting_at <= x_minutes_to_event,
                        models.UserPrescription.visiting_at > datetime.now(pytz.utc),
                    )\
                        .values(column('token'))
    ]
    
    # or

    tokens = [
        item[0]
        for item in db.query(models.UserNotificationsToken)\
            .join(
                models.UserPrescription,
                models.UserNotificationsToken.user_id == models.UserPrescription.user_id,
            )\
                .filter(
                    models.UserPrescription.visiting_at <= x_minutes_to_event,
                    models.UserPrescription.visiting_at > datetime.now(pytz.utc),
                )\
                    .values(column('token'))
    ]
```

but I got this errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <Mapper at 0x7f0921681fd0; User>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.

# or

sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <Mapper at 0x7f54970e4970; UserPrescription>. Please use the .select_from() method to establish an explicit left side, as well as providing an explicit ON clause if not present already to help resolve the ambiguity.
```

Comment: get_token function is not real. I write this part just for clarity. In real code I'll use this logic in repeatable background task in my FastAPI project.

Comment: I added (to first query) `.with_entities(*args)`, where `args` are fields of models, which were present in above query like `models.User.id` and others. After it I got correct result of query, so, probably, my question is solved, but I have no idea, why this solution solve my problem... If someone know reasons, help me to understand. Or, probably, there is a better solution, so I leave my question unanswered to get a more correct and detailed answer.

Comment: second query with `.with_entities(*args)` works correct too.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `values()` but it might be related to that.

Comment: I added a couple examples in an answer.  I'm using sqlalchemy 1.4 in case you are using < 1.4 the examples might not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
class UserNotificationToken(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_notification_tokens'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    token = Column(String)
    user = relationship('User', back_populates='tokens')


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    tokens = relationship(UserNotificationToken, back_populates='user')
    prescriptions = relationship('UserPrescription', back_populates='user')

class UserPrescription(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_prescriptions'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    visiting_at = Column(DateTime)

    user = relationship(User, back_populates='prescriptions')

metadata.create_all(engine)

class Config:
    MINUTES_TO_PRESCRIPTION = 60

with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    x_minutes_to_event = now + timedelta(minutes=60)

    # Example 1 with explicit joins.
    query = session.query(
        UserNotificationToken.token
    ).join(
        User, UserNotificationToken.user_id == User.id
    ).join(
        UserPrescription, User.id == UserPrescription.user_id
    ).where(
        and_(
            UserPrescription.visiting_at <= x_minutes_to_event,
            UserPrescription.visiting_at > now))
    for (token,) in query.all():
        print (token)

    # Example 2 with joins inferred from relationships.
    query = session.query(
        UserNotificationToken.token
    ).join(
        UserNotificationToken.user
    ).join(
        User.prescriptions
    ).where(
        and_(
            UserPrescription.visiting_at <= x_minutes_to_event,
            UserPrescription.visiting_at > now))
    for (token,) in query.all():
        print (token)

    # Example 3 join directly between tables with user_id FKs, use distinct
    query = session.query(
        UserNotificationToken.token
    ).join(
        UserPrescription, UserNotificationToken.user_id == UserPrescription.user_id
    ).where(
        and_(
            UserPrescription.visiting_at <= x_minutes_to_event,
            UserPrescription.visiting_at > now)).distinct()
    for (token,) in query.all():
        print (token)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution looks much better than mine. `.values()` works correct in my case, so it don't cause the problem. I use it just to take only a token from query, but now I've realized, that `query(UserNotificationToken.token)` does pretty much the same, but looks better. Thanks. I'll rewrite my code and use your tips.

Comment: @ALittleMoron I meant to drop the middle join originally but I guess I forgot.  I added a third example that drops the middle join because you can just join from `UserNotificationToken.user_id` directly to `UserPrescription.user_id`.  Sorry I remembered when I saw your comment.  Also to avoid duplicate tokens if there are more than one matching prescriptions in the join for a single token you should probably use `.distinct()` to get `SELECT DISTINCT user_notification_tokens.token ...`.